# Is the map from the circular half cone to the $xy$ plane a local isometry?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology

[image]

This is a text book exercise. And I think that this map is not a local isometry. But, I don't know how to show this question. Please help me explaining this question. Thanks a lot.

I posted its answer:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how the $t$-valued images relate to the question.

Comment: Idont understand as well. There is its answer. Can I post it if you want? @user99680

Comment: Sure, please do.

Comment: Okay I posted it @user99680

Comment: All I can think of is this relates to ruled surfaces, which the cone is an example of: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface  . LEt me think it thru some more.

Comment: I know ruled surface. But I cannot see the relation you said. Can you explain its answer step by step? @user99680

Comment: O.K: How about this: you take the line segment $(t,0,t)$, along the cone, i.e., the segment is contained in the intersection of the $xz$ plane with the cone. This segment has length $\sqrt {2} $ it maps down to the line segment $(0,0,t)$, and both have different lengths, which cannot happen for an isometry.

Comment: If this was an isometry, a segment of length $\sqrt {2}$ along the cone ( intersected with the $x-z$-plane, would map to a segment of length $\sqrt {2} $ also, but instead it maps to one of length $1$ . In general, $(t,0,t)$ along the cone will have length $\sqrt {2t^2}$ , but it will map thru $f$ into the segment $(t,0,0)$ with length $t$, and so the length is not preserved.Does that work for you?

Comment: Yes I udenrstand now. In order to be isometry, the lengths should be equal; that is, should be preserved. But in this exercise, the lengths not preserved, so not isometry. @user99680 thanks a lot:)

Comment: No problem; glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $$\pi : (C = \{ (x,y,z)|\ x^2+y^2=z^2 >0 \},g_C) \rightarrow ({\bf R}^2,g),\ (x,y,z)\mapsto (x,y)$$ where $g_C,\ g$ are metrics induced from ${\bf R}^3$.

If $c$ is a curve and $\pi$ is an local isometry then $$ g_C(c'(t),c'(t)) = g(\frac{d}{dt}\pi\circ c(t),\frac{d}{dt}\pi\circ c(t))$$

Hence $$ \int_1^2 g_C(c'(t),c'(t))^{1/2}\ dt = \int_1^2 g(\frac{d}{dt}\pi\circ c(t),\frac{d}{dt}\pi\circ c(t))^{1/2}\ dt$$

Hence local isometry preserves length.

Note that $c(t)=(t,0,t)$, $t\in [1,2]$, is a geodesic of length $\sqrt{2}$ on cone.

But $\pi\circ c(t)=(t,0,0) $ is a geodesic of length $1$.

Hence $\pi$ is not local isometry.